# Combine other rows with max values rows SQL

Tags: sql

I need to make a combination of queries from this table:

```
Lang, length, user, followers
-----------------------------
Esp,    10,   user0,   1
Esp,    20,   user1,   5
Eng,     5,   user2,  10
Eng,     2,   user3,  15
Jap,    25,   user4,   1
```

The idea is to group by language, show the language, number of rows, the average length and finally, the user and the followers of the user with the most followers.

Example of how the result should look like from the above table:

```
Lang, rows, avg, user, followers
 Esp,   2,  15, user1,   5
 Eng,   2, 3.5, user3,  15
 Jap,   1,  25, user4,   1
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    lang, COUNT(*) AS rows, 
    AVG(length) AS avg_length 
FROM
    toots 
GROUP BY
    lang 
LIMIT 10
```

I need to add the user with the most followers from all the rows grouped by lang. I don't know how I should add this case in the provided query.

Comment: And what would you expect with more than one user with a tie for followers?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a window function within a derived table, like as follows:

```
select Lang, Count(*) as rows, Avg(length) avg_length, 
  MaxFollower user, 
  Max(followers) followers
from (
  select *, First_Value(user) over(partition by Lang order by followers desc) MaxFollower
  from toots
) t
group by Lang, MaxFollower
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like below

```
SELECT T.*,
(
SELECT TS.user
FROM toots TS
WHERE 
    TS.Lang=T.lang 
    AND TS.followers=T.followers
ORDER BY user 
LIMIT 1
) AS user
FROM 
(
SELECT 
 lang, 
 count(*) as rows, 
 avg(length) as avg_length, 
 max(followers) as followers 
FROM toots 
GROUP BY lang 
)T
```